# Check if a string only contains the characters > or < or -

Tags: c#, regex

What I need is to check if a string only contains the characters `>` or `<` or `-`.

So I thought using a `RegEx` for this, and I found an SO question with the exact same problem, and it has an answer (not the accepted one but the answer with regex)

This is the SO question : [String contains only a given set of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293295/string-contains-only-a-given-set-of-characters)

So I modified the expression in this question to fit my needs like this :

```
static readonly Regex Validator = new Regex(@"^[><- ]+$");
```

and I call it like this ;

```
Validator.IsMatch(testValue)
```

But it's throwing the error

> x-y range in reverse order

There are lots of question on SO about this error but I cant find or understand the answer I need.

So what am I doing wrong with this `RegEx`?

Comment: No need escaping the hyphen if you [place the hyphen at the right place inside the character class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068725/3832970).

Comment: *Linq* alternative: `bool result = testValue.All(c => c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '-');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `-` within character groups. (`[0-9]` means "zero to nine" and not "zero, dash or nine")

Comment: how does one escape in regex ?

Comment: new Regex(@"^[><\- ]+$");

Comment: @DiabloSteve make that an answer, not a comment :/

Comment: generally `\-` but depending on the language you then need to escape the `\ ` as well within String-Objects: `\\-`

Comment: @dognose The @ before the string in C# means that escaping is automatic. They're called [verbatim string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, the answer is simple it was just never explained simple in most so answers

Comment: You only need to escape the `-` depending on its position, and according to the contents of the character set.

Answer (score 1):

`^[-<>]+$` "-" must come first in C# regex

Comment: Thanks, the answer is simple it was just never explained simple in most so answers

Comment: `-` symbol has a special meaning and should be escaped when we want to treat it litteraly, e.g. `[0-9]` is a range of characters `0, 1, 2, ..., 9` while `[0\-9]` means exactly `0`, `-` or `9` character.